# Adding a stored procedure to Using DATEDIFF

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I am getting the error "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'". I am trying:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `employeeAgeCheck`(IN `birthday` DATE) 
 NO SQL
SELECT DATEDIFF(year,`birthdate`,GETDATE()) AS bday
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHHrj.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I hope you are not trying to use sqlserver code in mysql coz that's a non runner..

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL [`DATEDIFF`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datediff.aspx) function takes only 2 parameters - two dates. You are passing three as if you were using the SQL Server `DATEDIFF` function. You need to ensure you are passing the correct parameters within your stored procedure.